# Не создается таблица в mapping Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Почему-то не создается таблица. Прописал мэппинг, указал его в hibernate.cfg.xml. Сессию создает, а таблица не создается.

user.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/> <!--autoincrement-->
        </id>
        <property name="firstname" column="first_name" type="string"/>
        <property name="lastname" column="last_name" type="string"/>
        <property name="age" column="age" type="int"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        " http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <!--<property name="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest"/>-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="user.cfg.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Java класс:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;`введите сюда код`
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что у вас в user.cfg.xml ?

Comment: @Vartlok сделал правку: добавил user.cfg.xml.
Вроде все нормально там. Может где-то что-то упустил.

Comment: @Rynkovoy table="users". схема не указана.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в смысле? какая схема должна быть указана?

Comment: @Rynkovoy ты же должен сказать в какой схеме находитися твоя таблица. а ты не указал. поэтому ничего не может найти

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а как указать схему?

Comment: @Rynkovoy `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">XXXXXX</property>`  либо `table="XXXXX.users"`

Comment: схема у Вас уже указана в ссылке подключения к БД `mydbtest`, лучше напишите вывод консоли при запуске приложения. У меня этот пример завелся, только указал полное название класса в user.cfg.xml